# Sending SMS with Facebook API

Tags: facebook, sms

I've been looking for any example or documentation about sending sms through facebook API but couldn't find official one.

I've also read some somewhere that SMS has been deprecated from facebook API. Then why is it still available in extended permissions?

Here's some documentation about it on facebook:
[Facebook developers](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/sms.send/)

Comment: Hi, When I click on the above link, it says "Page Not Found". Does it mean that Facebook has pulled down the SMS API?

Comment: If yes, is there any other way of achieving the same functionality using Facebook? Else, the only option would be to use a third-party service like Twilio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *has* been deprecated, insofar as it is part of the Legacy REST API, which while still functional, is being phased out in favour of the Graph API (and, to an extent, FQL).

I suspect that the permission remains in place so that developers have time to update applications that still use the REST API.